# WPF : Stop a ContextMenu from closing

Tags: c#, wpf

A Context Menu automatically closes when the user clicks outside of it. 
Is there a way to stop it from closing ? I tried setting the `StaysOpen` property to `true`  but failed to get the desired result.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

Use ContextMenuClosing event....
*"To suppress closing context menus, handlers of the event should mark it as handled"*
from msdn doc - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.contextmenuclosing%28VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

A bit unclear what you are trying to achive, maybe you should use Popup instead so you can close it whenever you want.